# How to find the row number of a row in a sorted MongoDB collection to calculate its percentile?

Tags: mongodb

I have a large MongoDB collection that contains a userID and a counter representing total hits for that user over time. I'd like to be able to calculate a given users percentile.

Conceptually, what I'd like to do is sort the collection and then get the row number for that given user's record and divide that number by the total count for the collection:

```
percentile = row_index / total_rows;
```

How would this be accomplished in MongoDB?

Answer (score 4):

Get total count by `db.yourCollection.count()`

Then count record that have larger number using
`db.yourCollection.find({$gte: value}).count()`

If total count = 1000, count for larger or equal = 950 then you've got in 950/1000 - top 95%

But if you use your collection often in read mode and rare in write mode I'd suggest to make new temp collection using MapReduce to have records `{_id:..., percent:...}`

Answer (score 1):

The trivial solution here is to sort by total hits descending. You then cursor through the results until you find your UserID.

Clearly, this solution does not provide great performance if you have to run it a lot. It's easy to get a "top 20", but it's far more computation get a "bottom 25%".

If this query is really important or you're running it a lot, there are couple of workarounds.

I think the easiest one is simply to run a job that builds the percentiles for you on a regular basis. Basically you build a collection that looks like this:

```
{ percent : 95, score : 888888 }
{ precent : 90, score : 777777 }
...
```

To get a user's percentile, you just look up their score in that relatively small collection. To update those scores, simply run a job on a regular basis that loops through all of the user.